# How can a non-Muslim who believes in Allah and the prophet Mohammed visit Mecca and Madina?

Tags: non-muslim, travelling

I am a non Muslim but believe that there is only one God and I also believe that prophet Mohammed is a messenger of God.

I heard in a lecture of Dr Zakir Nair that any body who believes in one God and that prophet Mohammed is his messenger can visit Mecca and Madina.

On giving written undertaking on his faith in Oneness of God.
Can anyone guide me how to visit Mecca and Madina under such circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

Travelling to Makkah/Madina needs an international passport and a valid visa for 'Umrah'. Travelling to any other city is just like an ordinary international city. Once you apply for the Umrah visa, the consulate would raise a flag due to your name. At this point, if you are able to convince the officer then you can travel.